# The Left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer. Unity 5 pro

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On line 14, i keep on getting an error: "The Left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer."

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RapidFireTrigger : MonoBehaviour {
    RapidFireTrigger Player;
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player enter the trigger");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            Destroy (gameObject);
    }
    void Start ()
    {
        RapidFireTrigger = GetComponent <PlayerShooting> ();
        PlayerShooting.timeBetweenBullets = 0.02f;
    }
    IEnumerator Wait ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (20);
    }

    void Restore ()
    {
        PlayerShooting.timeBetweenBullets = 0.15f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RapidFireTrigger = GetComponent <PlayerShooting> ();
```

RapidFireTrigger is a type.  You can't assign to it.  You can assign to a variable, like this:

```
var playerShooting = GetComponent <PlayerShooting> ();
```

Note: that assignment won't do anything to help you, though, unless you then go on to use its result somehow.